# Proxying Flash connections - suggestions for tools/configurations?

Tags: proxy, web-hosting, cache, flash

I have several users on a small network.

We all like to share YouTube, Hulu, and other Flash-based weblinks amongst ourselves. However, redownloading all that content seems inefficient.

I started with the Squid sample configuration for YouTube (http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/YouTube), but it either the Flash player is opening its own pipe outbound, or the proxy configuration is wrong - which seems to negate the benefit of the caching.

Is there a way to force the Flash player to use the proxy for this? Or have I perhaps missed something?

**Update** - I've earned the <kbd>Tumbleweed</kbd> badge on this one. Maybe this is harder than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried [this](http://cachevideos.com/)? Rewrites URLs and re-serves youtube vids with the aid of squid. May work with the other sites you mention also?

Comment: I have looked at that, now, too - looks like the closest thing to what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use iptables to have all outbound traffic to a remote port go through your proxy. But the problem is more complex than that. While Youtube uses HTTP, other sites use RTMP for flash streaming. To be best of my knowledge, there is no RTMP proxy available that would be useful for this.

Comment: and `iptables` won't help the Windows machines on the network, either